# VS 2015 class designer doesn't implement interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, class-diagram, class-designer

I use VS 2015 Comunity Edition.
My problem is that the Class Designer doesn't create implementations for members of interface. It doesn't do it both automatically and manually.
When I show inheritance with toolbox's inheritance line, I see lollipop, but implementation of interface is missing.
[image: Class diagram]

> The Inheritance connector can be used in one more way that results in automatic code generation.
>   In Figure 10-8 (left) an interface, ICrudActions, has been added to the diagram. When the Inheritance connector is dragged from a class to the interface, all the members of the interface are implemented on the class, as shown in Figure 10-8 (right).
>   [image: image 10-8]
>
> from "Bruce Johnson - Professional Visual Studio 2013"

When I try manually implement interface with the context menu, also nothing happens.
[image: Contex menu]

So, I have to go to the code and implement interface by intellisense.
[image]

Can someone help me?
P.S.: Sorry, for my bad English.

Comment: Can't help with an answer but I have confirmed the same behavior on my VS2015 installation with Update 2

Comment: Also can't help with an answer but I also have confirmed the same behavior here in VS2015 Update 1. Also tested in VS 2012, it works.

Comment: Thank you for answers. Probably, it is a bug.